# Компонент Аналог открытых вкладок Chrome

Tags: android, android-sdk

У меня есть список объектов типа `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass {
 public String title;
 public String comment;
 public ImageView photo;
}
```

Мне нужно представить эти объекты примерно так, как мобильный браузер Chrome представляет свои открытые вкладки (в виде стопки, фото с заголовком, с возможностью анимационного скролла и т.д.)

Есть ли готовые компоненты для подобной задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно есть - можете представлять данные как хотите: можете воспользоваться ListView, кастомизировать адаптер(читай, как отображать данные: где какое поле положить: текстове или фото) или воспользоваться его улучшенной версией RecycleView. За отображение данных отвечает адаптер, в который вы можете скормить нужный вам слой: [image: Слой для данных]

Comment: Вы видели, как выглядят вкладки в мобильном Google Chrome? Ничего похожего на ListView. На StackView больше похоже

Comment: @ИванМясников, вам нужно самому рисовать слой, как будут выглядеть данные